# PHP - Elvis Vs. Null coalesce

Tags: php

What is the difference between null coalesce operator and elvis?

```
$a = null;

echo $a ?: 'default1';

echo $a ?? 'default2';
```

It looks to me as they are doing the same job. However there must be difference. :)

Can someone point it out for me?

Comment: Hey, the exact same thing popped into my mind